# Ratings and review db schema

Tags: database, schema, database-schema

[Ratings and review schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I33x.png)

Can someone please have a look at the db schema (link above) I have designed and help me correct the mistakes(if any) / improve the design.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i check your schema. The rating and review tables have 1:1 relationship.  Can you combine into one table?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.
combining the tables would lead to many null values if there are no reviews for a particular rating.